# Can Solr index plain text files WITHOUT my having to run them through Tika?

Tags: solr, apache-tika

I'm only in the researching phase with Solr but so far it appears that to index an unstructured text file, I must convert it into XML using Tika?  Is this true?  I thought it odd that Lucene can tokenize and index arbitrary text without any conversion, yet Solr requires this extra step of converting to XML.  I thought maybe I was just missing something.

I'm looking into near-real-time full-text search for millions of files and hundreds of GB per day so the extra Tika conversion is troublesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the responses.  @javanna my question would've been better asked as "WITHOUT having to pre-process the input in any way".  There's just too many of them coming in too fast, they're too large, and speed is important. @Oklein when researching the DIH you mention, I stumbled upon this document:

http://www.lucidimagination.com/sites/default/files/file/whitepaper/LIWP_IndexingTextandHTMLFilesWithSolr.pdf

Basically the answer I'm pursuing is, use the ExtractingRequestHandler to process the plain text file and add extra fields on-the-fly.  Right now I'm using cURL which can add the fields using GET parameters, and will work on doing the equivalent using SolrJ.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler#SolrJ

Comment: PDF seems gone, anyone has a link?

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/LucidImagination/indexing-text-and-html-files-with-solr-4063407

Answer (score 1):

Check out the PlainTextEntityProcessor in the [DIH](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#PlainTextEntityProcessor)